# Some beginner questions:

Tags: modeling

SketchUp is my native software and I've noticed some differences that are causing me a ton of difficulty.

I made a rectangle and duplicated the top edge downwards, but it didn't divide the face into two faces. What's the proper way to do this?

[image]

I made a loop cut, but it measures from the middle. How do I measure from the top edge?
[image]

Why does deleting the edge delete the face? The faces are coplanar, so I don't see the need to delete the face. Why not just merge the faces?
[image]

I made some stairs, but the bottom stair has an internal face. What is the proper way to draw stairs? I looked up some tutorials and found one with the array modifier. But that's not really what I was looking for. I just want to make stairs.

I made this by making three loop cuts on a rectangular prism, then extruding each stair. 
[image]

Ideally, I don't want edge loops on the sides of the staircase because I might want to model things on the side of the stairs that don't match the edge loops.
[image]

I get that n-gons render terribly, but they're much easier to model with. Can I just model with n-gons, then convert it into quads later for renders?

How do I make handrails? In SketchUp, I just use follow-me to extrude a circle along a path. How do curves work in Blender? I can't figure out how to make them with architectural precision.

And finally, how does snapping work? I can't find any rhyme or reason to it. When I move objects around, it just snaps to random vertices. In SketchUp, you just select the vertice you want to move, then click on the vertice you want it to move to.
[image]

I really want to learn this program, but can't find any tutorials to answer my questions. Thank you!

Comment: Questions should be singular.  Please read [ask] for more information and take the [tour].  Also please read the [stack exchange help on asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/asking)

Comment: Why can't I ask more than one question in a post? For people who use such a complicated program, you'd think it wouldn't be a problem to answer multiple questions. Would you rather I make 7 different posts instead of one post with 7 questions? Because I need answers to every question.

Comment: @BlenderUser472819, that is the format of the platform - one question at a time. The title of your question should also be informative. Please describe your specific question with it. You will get better results if you mind the way Blender Stack Exchange is supposed to work.

Comment: @BlenderUser472819 Please understand that this site is not part of the blender foundation, it is a Stack Exchange site for blender users and enthusiasts, as such it follows a specific format.  Please read [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) if you are interested in the reasons for this policy.

Comment: You should also be aware that questions should show adequate effort to research before posting a question. In direct response to your desire to learn blender, I suggest watching Andrew Price's [Blender 2.8 Beginner Tutorial Series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U)

Comment: I've already watched many of his tutorials, but didn't see an answer to my question. I literally watched that tutorial before asking this and have done lots of research prior to asking these questions.

Comment: If you don't want to answer questions, then why are you guys even commenting? I don't appreciate the nitpicking over things that do not matter and the strictness of the rules turns me off to this community. Bye.

Comment: You seem to be so surprised that this site has its own rules... Probably you watched tutorials (e.g. in most of them won't be explained why Blender deletes the face if deleting the edge from technical side of things), but you didn't read the rules of the site. Asking one question per post *does* matter since allows searching through questions, answers here are not only for you rather for anyone searching for the same problem.

Comment: @BlenderUser472819 I posted the link to those tutorials as you wrote "I really want to learn this program, but can't find any tutorials to answer my questions", I thought it might have been helpful.  Obviously I was wrong, but for that I should not have to apologize. You could easily reduce your question to a single point and had it answered, instead of throwing a tantrum.  All communities have rules, if you don't want to abide by them then you should not expect to benefit.

Comment: FTR, the reason I commented was so I didn't have to flag it and it be closed without giving you the opportunity to correct it.  I was being less nitpicky!

Answer (score 4):

As others have pointed out in the comments, Stack Exchange is not a normal forum, and for the Q/A format to work, it is best when each question is a single question. That being said, all or your issues are fairly simple to explain and new software can be quite confusing - so even though these *should* be 7 separate answers on 7 separate questions....

**First question:** although there are many ways to cut a face in two, the easiest way to do it in this specific case is indeed the loopcut tool.

**Second question:** To measure a loopcut from the top edge of a plane, you can create the loopcut and slide it all the way to one side, then use the edge slide tool to move it a set amount. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to create the loopcut, and before clicking to set it in place, move the mouse until the loopcut is all the way to the edge you want to measure from. Press <kbd>G</kbd> twice to use the Edge Slide tool. (pressing <kbd>G</kbd> once would just be the move tool, which lets you move the selected vertices around unconstrained). Then with the edge slide tool active you can press <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> for an offset of -0.01 (blender units if you have no units specified, feet if you are using imperial units, or meters if you are using metric units). You can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> and then type other numbers to change your offset, or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you are happy with the offset.

**Third question:** Because when you select that single edge segment, you are really selecting the two vertices that make up that edge. When you press <kbd>Delete</kbd> it should open a menu for you to select what you want to delete. It is pretty self explanatory what the first five options do, but the ones after that are what you want if you want to model with Ngons.

[image]

(The first five options are geared more towards triangle or quad modeling, so with the first five delete options Blender will not try to merge faces). You can, however, use the dissolve options to remove the selected geometry without the surrounding edges or faces being messed up. In this case you could also use the "Edge Loops" delete option, but since that option's behavior has a lot of overlap with "Dissolve Edges" you likely won't need to use that option much.

**Fourth question:** Instead of making three loop cuts and extruding the bottom two one at a time, you could extrude the bottom two at the same time to the length of the middle stair, and then extrude the bottom one the rest of the way. To remove your internal face, add a loopcut on the bottom stair. Change the vertex snapping mode to vertex. Enable it, or just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while moving the loopcut.

by default in Blender 2.8 the snapping options will be at the top of the 3D view.

[image]

In Blender 2.79 the snapping options will be at the bottom of the 3D view.

[image]

Since snapping does not work with the Edge Slide tool, press  <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to move the selection and constrain it along the X axis, then hold  to use snapping. If you hold the mouse over one of the end vertices of the middle stair piece, it should snap the selection to be exactly in line with the other stair tread. From there you can select all and use the "Remove Doubles" option in Blender 2.79, or press <kbd>M</kbd> and select "By Distance" (same tool, just renamed). This will merge all selected vertices which are doubled up.
 From there you can simply select and delete the internal face and/or the internal edge (since that would delete the face too).

**Fifth question** From here you can use the dissolve options to make the side of your stairs a single face. You can absolutely model with Ngons, but it will lead to headaches later on if you want to refine your model and add more detail.

**Sixth question** Even if "how do curves work" was posted as a separate question entirely, it would probably get closed as too broad - it would practically require an in-depth tutorial on its own. You could start by setting the spline type to Poly instead of Bezier which will make it a lot closer to what you are familiar with, making paths in SketchUp to extrude shapes around. You can indeed model a fancy railing section and use use that as the geometry object for your curve, or just simply adjust the bevel, offset, and extrude settings in curve's geometry section to display a simple shape along its length. You can make a circle run the length of the curve by leaving the offset and extrude at 0, and increasing the bevel.

**Seventh question** There are multiple different snapping options (see above images for where to find them in Blender 2.8 vs Blender 2.79). Snapping can behave weirdly, but if you want to line up an object by moving one vertex so it snaps to the vertex on another object, you can simply move one of the objects normally until it is quite close to where you want it, and then the snapping *should* move the object the least distance possible, meaning that it will seek to snap together the two vertices that you already moved close into position.

Comment: It must be hat season. :D

Comment: ... and should not be answered as the question stands!